# 'Awkward' Element Selection

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery set up to hide certain elements by ID so that I can conditionally show some back up based on user input.

To give some context, this is for an commerce website where users will need to select a clothing type, colour and size. The sizes are specific to each clothing type so this is the element I want to show/hide.

The jQuery I'm using is made up of the following (not very DRY but I wanted to get everything working first so I could see exactly what was going on):

```
$('#picker_pa_ladies-size').hide();
$('#picker_pa_ladies-size').parent().siblings(".label").hide();
$('#picker_pa_t-shirt-size').hide();
$('#picker_pa_t-shirt-size').parent().siblings(".label").hide();
$('#picker_pa_vest-top-size').hide();
$('#picker_pa_vest-top-size').parent().siblings(".label").hide();
```

and what I want to do next is:

```
if (the class ‘selected’ is on anchor element with (attribute) title ‘ladies’) {
    $('#picker_pa_ladies-size').show();
    $('#picker_pa_ladies-size').parent().siblings('.label').show();
}
```

The products are managed through the WooCommerce plug in on a WordPress platform so I can't easily edit the html for each variation.

I've tried searching both SO and the rest of the Internet to find a method of selecting the elements I need but can't seem to find anything - apologies if I've missed something.

[Site Link](http://henpartyshop.com/product/cocktail-glass/)

Comment: The selector for `the class ‘selected’ is on anchor element with (attribute) title ‘ladies’` would be `$("a.selected[title='ladies']")`

Comment: `if ($("a.selected").attr("title") === "ladies") { ... }`